# Is the parsed route information available in the DI container at the time a controller is instantiated?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

In support of multi-tenancy, setting up routing:

```
{controller}/{tenantId}/{action}/{id?}
```

When the controller is instantiated, via the IoC framework in MVC6, the constructor takes a model (`IUserStore<ApplicationUser>`) that manages access to users and needs the tenantId in its constructor.  The DI container is barfing right now b/c it doesn't have the tenantId.

I'd like to be able to register the model thusly:

```
services.TryAddTransient(typeof(IUserStore<CazadorUser>, (IServiceProvider isp) =>
{
     return new TenantUserStore<ApplicationUser>(isp.GetService<DbContext>(), "Can I get the tenant ID from the IServiceProvider as its in the route?");
 }));
```

If I cannot access the parsed route, is there another way to get the tenant ID into the DI-hydrated controller (or, rather, the ctor parameter of the DI-hydrated controller that is DI-hydrated)?

Comment: I am curious, What are you trying to achieve ? You will get the tenantId in your action method. Is that not enough to pass to your other layers ?

Comment: @Shyju I would like the IUserManager impl that supports multitenancy to be passed to the controller via DI. It seems like the happy path for MVC 6, and I kind of buy into DI.

Comment: DI containers are meant for [composing object graphs](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) (typically once at application startup), not for defining runtime behavior. When you need to change a dependency at runtime, you should turn to [abstract factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/12/24/placement-of-abstract-factories/) or the [strategy pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499442/best-way-to-use-structuremap-to-implement-strategy-pattern#1501517).

Comment: Do not inject runtime data into your constructors; that's [an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).